# MySQL сложный запрос JOIN

Tags: mysql

Уважаемые, небольшой ступор как сделать запрос. Есть две таблицы, в одной данные для каждого объекта, а во второй его состояние(id, время когда было изменение). Требуется сделать выборку чтобы получить список всех объектов и их последнее изменение, то есть вывести все объекты и если изменение в выбранной дате было то записать это время, если изменения не было(нет соответствующей записи таблицы) то записать NULL. Как составить запрос?
Пробовал таким запросом но условие неправильное немного. По разному пробовал либо не полностью возвращает либо ничего.

```
SELECT `objects`.`id`, `objects`.`weight`, `objects`.`price`,
       `objects`.`status`, MAX(status.changeStatusTime)
  FROM `objects` 
    LEFT JOIN `status` ON `status`.`id_obj` = `objects`.`id`
  WHERE DATE(status.changeStatusTime) = '2017-02-05'
  GROUP BY `objects`.`id`
```

[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]

Comment: status.id_obj это же внешний ключ ссылающийся на objects.id? Тогда почему в примере они различаются? Для избежания разночтений хорошо было бы выложить полноценную структуру куда-нибудь на sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: Извиняюсь, немного напутал с id_obj, там 1 и 2 вместо 10 и 11

Comment: Условие `DATE(status.changeStatusTime) = '2017-02-05'` лучше писать так: `status.changeStatusTime>= '2017-02-05' and  status.changeStatusTime<'2017-02-05'+interval 1 day`. Выглядит более громоздко, но скорость поиска может оказаться в десятки раз выше, особенно при наличии индекса на поле с датой. Применение любой функции к колонке таблицы заставляет БД во первых делать вычисления на каждой записи, во вторых дерает невозможным использование индексов и запрос вынужден просмотреть всю таблицу целиком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно угадал со смыслом вопроса, то как-то так:

```
SELECT o.id, o.weight, o.price, o.status, s.ts
  FROM `objects` AS o
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_obj, MAX(changeStatusTime) AS ts
                  FROM `status`
                  WHERE DATE(status.changeStatusTime) = '2017-02-05'
                  GROUP BY id_obj
              ) AS s ON s.id_obj = o.id
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно. Теперь разобрался с о вложенным запросом в JOIN